# No service for type 'Duende.IdentityServer.Stores.ISigningCredentialStore' has been registered

Tags: c#, identityserver4, identity

I'm trying to get Identity running locally in an API.

Here is my program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();

builder.Services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(options =>
    options.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2
);


builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    
 options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


builder.Services.Configure<JwtOptions>(options => builder.Configuration.GetSection("JWT").Bind(options));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

When I try to hit an endpoint in my API I get the following:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Duende.IdentityServer.Stores.ISigningCredentialStore' has been
> registered.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
> provider, Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
> provider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext
> messageReceivedContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext
> context, String scheme)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

I've tried searching online and even reviewing their documentation but still not able to resolve this.

Comment: same error here